# Installing visualizer for boost::posix_time::ptime in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

When debugging an application with boost::posix_time::ptime instances in it, the normal debugger is not very helpful, as it only shows a time value in ticks. When outputting the same object with `std::cout`, the console shows the time in a readable format.

Now I know of the existance of debug visualizers, which can format the values to a readable format in the debugger. There is even a handy installer for a tool that includes the debug visualizer for boost::posix_time at [msdn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c7e02633-86d9-4262-b745-6cc647afb3a8).

However, when trying to install this tool, I get the error message "This extention is not installable on any currently installed products.". Maybe this is because I am using an express version of Visual Studio 2012, but I don't think so, as it does support other tools and extentions.

Boost does provide [the files](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost_docs/subprojects/DebuggerVisualizers/) to install the debug visualizer, but there is no help regarding how to install them. Visual Studio help only mentions how to install some `.DLL` files with the visualizer in it, while the files provided by Boost are `.txt` and `.hpp` files.

So, I still don't know how to install a visualizer for boost::posix_time. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Express versions even support installing debug visualizers as their extensibility is fairly restricted.

VS2012 also uses a new format for the debug visualizers so unless the ones you are trying to install are in the new format (which is XML-based IIRC and not backward compatible) you're not going to get anywhere with them. The ones you linked are in the old format, and to install them on a pre-VS2012 Visual Studio, you put them into the appropriate sections of the autoexp.dat file that you find in the Visual Studio directory tree.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So VS2012 does not support the old format debug visualizers on the boost SVN server?

Comment: That is my understanding.